# How to make searchable drop-down in adaptive cards

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I have a message extension in which one of the `Action command` shows a form which is basically an adaptive card. The card contains a drop-down.

Here I am interested is there any way to perform the search on the list.

See the image and code below for more clearance.

I am developing in `Node.js`

```
            const card = CardFactory.adaptiveCard({
            version: '1.0.0',
            type: 'AdaptiveCard',
            body: [

                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "Route Name",
                    "size": "Medium",
                    "weight": "Bolder",
                    "spacing": "Large"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
                    id: "routeId",
                    "spacing": "small",
                    "choices": routedDd,
                    "placeholder": "Select an option",
                    "value": "Select an option"
                }
            ],

            actions: [
                {
                    type: 'Action.Submit',
                    title: 'Submit'
                }
            ]
        });

        return {
            task: {
                type: 'continue',
                value: {
                    card: card,
                    heigth: 200,
                    width: 400,
                    title: 'Add Task'
                }
            }
        };
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think this feature hasn't yet been released, but it's on the roadmap. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SEsjrFIf110

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Input.ChoiceSet`.

Here is an example:

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.6",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
            "choices": [
                {
                    "title": "Choice 1",
                    "value": "Choice_1"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Choice 2",
                    "value": "Choice_2"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Choice 3",
                    "value": "Choice_3"
                }
            ],
            "isMultiSelect": false,
              "style": "filtered",
              "id": "choiceSelect",
            "placeholder": "Type anything to search.."
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the Microsoft documentation for typeahead search with Input.ChoiceSet, including examples and screenshots: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/dynamic-search?tabs=desktop%2Cnodejs

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**